# How to flatten the RNN output for Dense layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I'd like to classify a signal containing

`X = (n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features)`, where `n_samples=476`, `n_timesteps=400`, `n_features=16` are the number of samples, timesteps, and features (or channels) of the signal.

`y = (n_samples, n_timesteps, 1)`. Each timestep is labeled by either 0 or 1 (binary classification).

My graph model is shown in the figure below.

[image]

The input is fed into a 32-unit LSTM. The LSTM output enters a 1-unit Dense layer to generate a 400x1 vector, where 400 is the number of timesteps. I then would like to put this 400x1 vector into a 400-unit Dense layer. I tried to flatten the 1-unit Dense, but the shape of the final output does not match the label 400x1 vector.

The snippet and model are shown as follows.

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(n_timestep, n_feature))
lstm1 = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
dense1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(lstm1)
flat1 = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(dense1)        
dense2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(400, activation='sigmoid'))(flat1)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=dense2)
model.summary()
```

[image]

The error is seen below.

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_4 to have shape (400, 400) but got array with shape (400, 1)
```

Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: You already have the desired output after the Dense layer (i.e. a prediction for each timestep). Why are you adding those two TimeDistributed layers to the model?

Comment: @today. I'd like to filter some noises from the output of dense_3 using neural net.

Comment: I don't think adding a Dense layer like that helps you to reduce the noise. Besides, the `y` has a shape of `(400, 1)`, therefore the last layer also should have a shape of `(400,1)` and not `(400,400)` (and that is exactly what the error says). If you would like to increase the capacity of your net then add a Dense layer with size 4 or 8 or 16 after the LSTM layer and before the Dense layer with size one and sigmoid activation (and just remove those TimeDistributed layers).

Comment: Can you describe your problem a bit, it is not clear, what you want to do. The architecture does not really make sense. If you want to have 1 element for each timestep you have to use TimeDistributed around the Dense(1) layer.

Comment: @Digital-Thinking, that is not necessary at all. (It used to be in Keras 1).

Comment: @today 's comment is very precise.

Comment: Thanks for your all comments. I'd like to explain my problem. LSTM returns a sequence of 0 and 1, where 0 and 1 are the labels of each timestep. Most of the time, y_true is 0. However, in y_pred, there are many spikes, or 1. Each spike lasts for only several timesteps. We can call them false positive values. My idea is to use neural network to remove those spikes, or noise. That's why I'd like to stack another network after LSTM.

Comment: So you simply want to stack another Dense layer to the model, right? There are 2 scenarios. If you want to apply the same layer to all timestep, you can use TimeDistributed, where all parameters are applied and updated at the same time to all timesteps. If you want to apply the same structure with independent params to all timestep, you can slice the tensor using Lambda layer and apply whichever layer that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your all comments. I found a way by using Reshape().